# Custom Javascript Ajax for ASP.NET

Tags: c#, javascript

I've written some basic Javascript functions and would like to learn how to enable asynchronous postbacks within a C# 4.0/ASP.net project using this JS code.

For example, I have a script that increments a number when clicked.  When clicked again, the number is decremented.  I basically load the number from a database, then hide one `<span>` and show another with the corresponding decremented number on click.  This is not complicated javascript; its a simple example.  Now when I click the button I want to send this increment/decrement call back to the server to update the database's number.

I realize that I can accomplish something akin to this example using the AJAX Control Toolkit's toggle button.  I, however, want to know how to use my OWN javascript to create AJAX functionality.

How do I accomplish this using C# and my custom Javascript code?

I'm not opposed to using the ASP.net AJAX library, I just don't want to use a ready built control.  I want to learn the process of creating my own AJAX functionality.  I would presume that I will have to use an `asp:UpdatePanel`, but I don't know how to call C# functions from the client side.

My javascript is not jQuery, in fact I want nothing to do with jQuery until I learn more about javascript and this process.

Comment: Honestly javascript is pretty much a dead language that has been replaced by jQuery.

Comment: @Chris: has C# has been replaced by .NET as well? :)

Comment: @Chris - jQuery **is** JavaScript.

Comment: +1 for wanting to understand what's really happening under the hood.

Comment: jQuery is what javascript should have been originally, prior to jQuery it was a completely inferior language. And @fear your analogy is backwards, your statement should be more along the lines has IL been replaced by C# (or .NET)? And the answer would be yes, yes it has. You can write IL directly if you want but have fun with that.

Comment: C# is a language. jQuery isn't, its a library. So I don't agree with your analogy. And there's nothing really fundamentally wrong with javascript anyway, the problem is that theres a hundred different interpreters out there, all of which have their own bugs and quirks.

Comment: "theres a hundred different interpreters out there" that sounds like a gigantic defect to me. And I disagree, jQuery is a language. It might built on top of javascript but it's definitely superseded javascript.

Comment: jQuery uses Javascript, without JS jQ doesn't function. What jQuery does is enable you to use JavaScript more easily as a series of function calls, so it isn't really a language in its own right - everything you can do in jQ you could do in JS if you spent the time coding it.  Don't think I'm knocking jQ though - it is immensely cool and I really like it, but there are a lot of diff 
JS interpreters out there, and ppl sometimes do their own thing with it, which is annoying (IE)

Comment: The simple fact of the matter is, if you suck at Javascript, although you might not realize it, you also suck at jQuery.  BECAUSE jQuery IS Javascript.  Your sucky code just sucks less because there's a big ole nanny holding your hand to make sure it works regardless of your sucky code.  Many of us were coding these complex behaviors prior to jQuery, and doing a good job of it.  And will continue to, if the jQuery LIBRARY expects to continue to dominate the market (support).

Answer (score 2):

Simple with no UpdatePanel:

First, add a Generic Handler to your project (.ashx). This will act as our Http endpoint. Our javascript will call it. We could (and probably should), use a web service endpoint but that requires processing the response and complicates the example. A handler returns plain text.

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="Handler" %>

using System;
using System.Web;

public class Handler : IHttpHandler
{
    // We'll use a static var as our "database".
    // Feel free to add real database calls to the increment
    // and decrement actions below.
    static int TheNumber = 0;

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {       
        string action = context.Request.QueryString["action"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(action))
        {
            if (action == "increment")
                TheNumber++;   //database update and fetch goes here
            else if (action == "decrement")
                TheNumber--;   //database update and fetch goes here           
        }
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Write(TheNumber);
    }

    public bool IsReusable { get { return false; } }
}
```

Next, create your web page and add the async javascript.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#"%>
<html>
<head runat="server">    
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // An XMLHttpRequest object is required to make HTTP requests.
    // Try a couple instantiation strategies to handle different
    // browser implementations.
    function createXMLHttpRequest() {
        try { return new XMLHttpRequest(); } catch (e) { }
        try { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); } catch (e) { }
        try { return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); } catch (e) { }
        alert("XMLHttpRequest not supported");
        return null;
    }

    function callHandler(action) {
        var xmlHttpReq = createXMLHttpRequest();
        // We're interested in an asychronous request so we define a 
        // callback function to be called when the request is complete.
        xmlHttpReq.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlHttpReq.readyState == 4 && xmlHttpReq.status == 200)
                document.getElementById("<%= lbl.ClientID%>").innerHTML 
                    = xmlHttpReq.responseText;
        }
        xmlHttpReq.open("GET", "Handler.ashx?action=" + action, true);
        xmlHttpReq.send(null);
    }  
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="Form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    The Number:&nbsp;<Label runat="server" id="lbl">0</Label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Increment" 
            OnClientClick="callHandler('increment');return false;" />
        &nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Decrement" 
            OnClientClick="callHandler('decrement');return false;" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The final flow is:

- A web page user clicks the Increment or Decrement button which calls our javascript
- Our javascript sends a request with the desired action in the querystring to Handler.ashx
- Handler.ashx reads the querystring, increments or decrements its static variable, and returns the value
- Our callback receives the value and updates our UI.

Answer (score 0):

if your using an `UpdatePanel` it's very simple with a JavaScript call to `__doPostBack`. See [here for example](http://aspalliance.com/895_Understanding_the_JavaScript___doPostBack_Function.2).

Comment: Question states that he doesn't want to use a ready built control. BTW JQuery is a library built using JavaScript. Javascript LIVES!

Comment: question also **explicitly states he doesn't mind using an update panel**. and where exactly did i even mention jquery in my answer? just FYI, since you're obviously retarded, neither __doPostBack nor UpdatePanel have anything whatsoever to do with jQuery. The level of retardedness reaches a new low every time I visit this site.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this tutorial around AJAX
http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/Default.Asp

It will give you an overview of using Javascript to GET and POST data using AJAX.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link on how you can incorporate ASP.NET C# with your custom Javascript code.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386450.aspx

It also contains a sample VS 2010 project here:
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=185646

Here's generally what's going on here:

In the **AjaxIScriptControl** solution:

**SampleTextBox.cs** - takes care of rendering the script control on the page; and attachment to client javascript code (the js file)

**SampleTextBox.js** - takes care of client side functionality and generates Javascript object of control via prototype

**Notes:**

- This example leverages existing
  ASP.NET's built-in control (you
  notice SampleTextBox inherits Textbox
  and IScriptControl) but you can
  render any type of HTML control if
  you inherit *ScriptControl class*
  instead.
- This solution also chose to separated
  the Script control code and website
  code in two projects but you can
  easily make it into one.
- You can easily leverage another Javascript library in your JS file

In my experience so far, this is the one of the more elegant way to incorporate server side code with client side if you are to create re-useable controls for your website.  You leverage server side power to do the initial rendering while provide client side capabilities through Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If you create your C# functions as [WCF REST Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/cc950529.aspx) or older-style [Script Services](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2006/12/28/understanding-asp-net-ajax-web-service-proxies.aspx), then you can easily call your service methods from your JavaScript using a basic XmlHttpRequest (no jQuery or UpdatePanels needed).

Here's a quick jsFiddle I put together: http://jsfiddle.net/ndVeS/

This sample has two text boxes; you enter a value in the first one, click the button, and then that value is passed to a service (an echo service) and returned in the callback.  The JavaScript code takes that value and populates the second textbox with it.

You could define a C# WCF RESTful service like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public class EchoService : IEchoService {
  [WebGet(UriTemplate="EchoMe?val={theValue}, ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
  public string EchoMe(string theValue) {
    return theValue;
  }
}
```

If you handle your calls this way, you can separate out your service logic from your presentation (ASPX files), and this allows for easier testing and you can also separate responsibilities from those who build the UI from those that build the business functionality.

I have to admit I'm more of a jQuery person when it comes to this, but I thought it's a great exercise to figure out how the XmlHttpRequest works under the hood.  It makes you appreciate what jQuery (or similar framework) provides.

Here's a nice overview of the XmlHttpRequest object and how to use it: http://www.jibbering.com/2002/4/httprequest.html

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
function GetXmlHttpObject(handler) {
var objXMLHttp = null
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    objXMLHttp = new XMLHttpRequest()
}
else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    objXMLHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
}
return objXMLHttp;
```

}

function GetDropDown() {

```
function stateChanged(StatesUpdated) {


    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 || xmlHttp.readyState == "complete") {
        document.getElementById('updateplace').innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
        //"updateplace" is you div id which will hold the new data or new page
        if (navigator.appName != "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {

        }
    }
    else {
        //alert(xmlHttp.status);
    }
}





xmlHttp = GetXmlHttpObject()
if (xmlHttp == null) {
    alert("Browser does not support HTTP Request");
    return;
}



    url = "xyz.aspx" //this might be sent to any post data
    url = url + "&sid=" + Math.random();


    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = stateChanged;

    xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);

    xmlHttp.send(null);
```

}

with the above code you can send data to any .cs file also where you can change the data and load it in a new page which will load in the update div and the method should redirect to the new aspx file.

I hope you got the logic :)

if you have any doubts reach me @ sankalpa.sam@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not MVC that you're doing, but have a look at the MVC section of the ASP.NET site and you will find a lot of examples of AJAX calls there - MVC doesn't use those dreadful script-soup creating .NET objects.  Most will probably be using jQuery - this is an open-source javascript library that can plug into any web app and provides some really nice functionality.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe u r looking for this:

function ajaxscript(){
$.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: |url/methodName|,
                  data: |variable_name|,
                  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                  dataType: "json",
                  success: |some javascript here|,
                  error: |some javascript here|
            });

Comment: Code should be formatted as such, and you don't bother to mention that this isn't native code... you're using a library (jQuery, I'm pretty sure).  I realize that jQuery has become largely synonymous with Javascript (see comments above), but there IS a distinction.